# Multiple divs on top multiple images

Tags: html, css, image

How to make multiple images with a tag name as a link on top of each one?
I can make **only one** image with a tag name on top of the image, but not other ones. Somehow when I copy the whole div (contains the img and the tag's div), it doesn't show the tags on other images.

I've tried: `position: relative` for the parent div, `position: absolute` for the tag (child div), make the image `float: left`.
I've also tried to "stick" the child div with its parent.
I've tried adding div and class for each item: image, image container, tag, a tag...

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  /*I've tried with px, doesn't make a difference*/
  float: left;
  /*I've also tried adding a class for img and position: absolute*/
}

.nameTag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nameText {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="assets/images/img1.png" />
  <div class="nameTag"><a href="" class="nameText">Mobile App</a></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="assets/images/img2.png" />
  <div class="nameTag"><a href="" class="nameText">Mobile App</a></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="assets/images/img3.png" />
  <div class="nameTag"><a href="" class="nameText">Mobile App</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a JSFiddle with some code example of how it went wrong, so we can help you correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is *exactly* what you are looking for but this is what I've changed in your `CSS`:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; //allowed images to float
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.nameTag {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    top: 100px; //positioned about half way down the image
    text-align: center; //center the link text
}
```

Here is a link to the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kotsenburg/pen/LjyPaz) for you to view.  Let me know!

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need. The trick is "display: inline-block". I didn't know about that.

Comment: @vietnguyen No problem! A `<div>` tag is defaulted to a `block` level element, which means it takes up its own line.  Changing its `display: inline-block;` allows it to be floated on the same line as another element.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your float to "none" or copy/paste this into your html/css files.

Hope this helps.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  /*I've tried with px, doesn't make a difference*/
  float: none;
  /*I've also tried adding a class for img and position: absolute*/
}


/* ^^^ Change float to "none"...seems to work here */

.nameTag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nameText {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nameTag"><a href="" class="nameText">Mobile App</a></div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlUiyrmhTXFppqk4aYzqTOU9nimCQsYibukwAV8rstsDkAVQT-mA" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="nameTag"><a href="" class="nameText">Mobile App</a></div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlUiyrmhTXFppqk4aYzqTOU9nimCQsYibukwAV8rstsDkAVQT-mA" />

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="nameTag"><a href="" class="nameText">Mobile App</a></div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlUiyrmhTXFppqk4aYzqTOU9nimCQsYibukwAV8rstsDkAVQT-mA" />
</div>
```